# How do I run the screen command in background and record data to log file?

Tags: shell, terminal, zsh

I have a Z Shell (`zsh`) script that executes a series of commands to install a device on my computer (Mac). One of the commands is to read the MAC address from the device, which the device will do once it turns on for the first time.

Before the device sends data via Serial , there is a delay on the device to allow a serial capture command to be executed, I want to capture the mac address which the device will print out, then terminate the serial capture (kill the process) after about 5 seconds and proceed with the script. I am attempting to do this using the screen command. I am able to record to a log but I cannot run screen in the background.

Note:
The `-L` writes the file to a log called `screenlog.0`

I have the following command to do this.

```
screen -L /dev/tty.usbserial-D3086KU0 115200
```

However adding an ampersand to the end does not run it in the background as I would expect.It still takes me to the screen.

```
screen -L /dev/tty.usbserial-D3086KU0 115200 &
```

How do I make screen work and capture serial output in the background or how do I achieve this using some other equivalent?

Answer (score 1):

I will be honest, I have never tried screen before. But, looking in the man page, I see this:

> -d -m   Start screen in "detached" mode. This creates a new session but doesn't attach to it. **This is useful for system startup
> scripts**.
>
> -D -m   This also starts screen in "detached" mode, but doesn't fork a new process. The command exits if the session terminates

I would try this :-)